# LINQ: Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, linq, generics, ienumerable

I write this code in C# with LINQ. Type of `innerResult2` is `IEnumerable<out T>`

this part of code has exception :

> Nullable object must have a value

```
var innerResult2 = (from Vw_WorkFlow_Cartable in innerResult
 select new
 {
     isedit = (bool?)Convert.ToBoolean((
       (from v in view8.Table.AsEnumerable()
        where
          v.Field<bool?>("SendByRequester") == true 
        select new
        {
            ActivityID = v.Field<Guid>("ActivityID")
        })
        .Contains(new 
        { 
            ActivityID = (System.Guid)Vw_WorkFlow_Cartable.Field<Guid?>("ActivityID") 
        }) 
        ? true : false))
 })
```

Comment: Can you edit your question so the code is more readable?

Comment: Is `"ActivityId"` `null`? You cast from nullable (`Guid?`) to non-nullable (`Guid`) type, if it's null then it will give you error.

Comment: change v.Field<bool?>("SendByRequester") == true to v.Field<bool?>("SendByRequester").HasValue && v.Field<bool?>("SendByRequester")  == true

Comment: `(from ...where... select new {...}).Contains(new {...})` this code should never work, what is the comparer? and why are you trying to `Convert.ToBoolean(bool boolValue)`?

Comment: and `Contains(...) ? true: false` is another redundant.